# Combobox won't select any item when clicking in margin between items

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, layout, combobox

This problem is probably best explained with a video. See here: http://youtu.be/r_phl8g9AzY
Basically, selection in my combobox works just fine when the mouse is over the selection rectangle, but there's an area in between the selection rectangles for each item where the next item won't highlight, but if you click while the mouse is in this region, it acts as if you've clicked outside of the combobox- that is, it reverts to the old selection. I would instead expect it to select the currently highlighted item.

I've googled regarding this issue thinking it might be a general WPF issue, but found nothing, so I assume it's something in my styling. The combobox does use some templates- I'm not really sure what's relevant, so I've pasted most of it below. I've tried messing around with the combobox item rectangle radii a little bit without success. The actual instance of the combobox doesn't override any of these settings. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxToggleButton}" x:Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="false" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" >
            <TextBox Visibility="Hidden" Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTextBox}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,3" x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Style="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="True" Background="{DynamicResource LightBrush}" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource NormalBorderBrush}" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
        </ToggleButton>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,23,3" x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="Popup" Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
            <Grid MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" />
                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollViewer}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="95" TargetName="DropDownBorder" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.5" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="AllowsTransparency" SourceName="Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" TargetName="DropDownBorder" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" TargetName="ContentSite" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOn">

                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="HoverOff">

                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="HoverRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOn">

                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000" Value="1" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="SelectedOff">

                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedRectangle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    </Storyboard>

                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Margin="1,1,1,1">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Background" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0.25" Fill="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="HoverRectangle" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource NormalBrush}" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedRectangle" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Fill="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5,2,0,2" x:Name="contentPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Visibility="Collapsed" Stroke="{StaticResource HoverShineBrush}" StrokeThickness="1" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOff}" x:Name="SelectedOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SelectedOn}" x:Name="SelectedOn_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOff}" x:Name="HoverOff_BeginStoryboard"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource HoverOn}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is hardly a bug, if you set a margin there is no item in that place so why should one be selected?

Just remove the `Margin` on the outmost `Grid` and wrap it in a `Border` with an equivanlent `Padding`, that creates the same results but should be clickable now (possibly the `Border.Background` should be set to `Transparent` if there is no hit-testing yet).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same behavior which I fixed by removing the padding on the border surrounding the `ContentPresenter` for the `ComboBoxItem`. I replaced it using a margin on the `ContentPresenter` instead.

#### Click between items not Selecting Highlighted ComboBoxItem

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
  <Border Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="2" Padding="2">
    <ContentPresenter />
   </Border> 
   <!-- ...removed for brevity -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

#### FIX: Clicks between items now Select Highlighted ComboBoxItem

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
  <Border Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" CornerRadius="2">
    <ContentPresenter Margin="2" />
   </Border> 
   <!-- ...removed for brevity -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does removing the `Margin="1,1,1,1"` from the `Grid` in your `ComboBoxItem` `ControlTemplate` or the `Margin="5,2,0,2"` from the ContentPresenter inside of that `Grid` make any difference at all?

It's got to be a margin/padding thing on your `ComboBoxItem` `ControlTemplate` I would think.